# Java SQL: Long connection vs Short connections

Tags: java, sql-server

I am having lots of connection problems when working with Microsoft server and creating the connection from java.

I need to communicate with db in average every 2 sec, for verity of things. Most of my queries are within the 500 milliseconds.

About every 15 min or so, I am having a connection drop and one of my queries is failing. I got a retry mechanism, that always work within 3 tries.

My only problem is that, 500 milliseconds query turns to be 2 sec or longer when there is a connection drop.

What would be the best approach of connection to SQL server, the way I do it now:

- create `Connection`
- create `Statement`
- execute it
- and close both the statement and the connection

Or should I keep the connection opened and only create multiple statements for each of my queries?

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Server machine? Could it be that it's slow / flakey?

Comment: Is your application and SQL Server on the same machine?

Comment: @yshavit yeah, I been looking at my logs and also create a pinger to check connection. There is no problem there

Comment: @WEI_DBA no they are not

Answer (score 0):

Let us take one issue at a time, first the `Connection`.
`Connection` to a database is resource intensive, to create and to hold on to. It would be wiser to create a pool of connections and hold on to them until your application stops. A connection pool manager may be of great help in this context. I have personally used Apache's [DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) and found to be convenient and efficient. There could other alternatives too. When you need a connection borrow one from the pool and return it when its use is complete.

Comment: And use the features of the pool to ensure a connection is still valid before borrowing, and occasionally while the connection is idle.